# Resolve as duplicate in JIRA SOAP

Tags: php, jira

I couldn't find any way to close as duplicate in JIRA soap, any idea which method to use and how to use?

```
$rIssue= array();
$rIssue['resolution']  = 3;

$soap->progessWorflowAction($auth,$issue,21,$rIssue);
```

But this marks its as Resolved fixed instead of duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same issue we had before with your update issue problem.

The fourth param of this argument is expecting an array of RemoteFieldValue objects.

Try this:

```
<?php

    class RemoteFieldValue {
        var $id;
        var $values = array();

        function __construct($idIn, $valuesIn) {
            $this->id = $idIn;
            $this->values = $valuesIn;
        }
    }

    $rfv = new RemoteFieldValue('resolution', array("id" =>"3"));

    $rfvArray = array($rfv);

    $soap->progessWorflowAction($auth,$issue,21,$rIssue);


?>
```

Or try modifying your example like this:

```
// Since you are using an associative array I'll assume this is your RmeoteFieldValue object
$rIssue= array();

// The id of a remote field object is a string ("resolution") and the value needs to be an array of Strings (["3"]), even though you are only sending one
$rIssue['resolution']  = [3];

//Now you have your RemoteFieldVaue object, but the call is expecting an array of them, even if you are only sending one
$rfvArray = [$rIssue];

// Make the call with the new array as the fourth param
$soap->progessWorflowAction($auth,$issue,21,$rfvArray);
```